# slow typing in between <?php tags with eclipse helios with pdt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I get slow typing in between `<?php` tags with eclipse helios with pdt

windows 7 / dual core / 3gb ram
using 3.6.1 M20100909-0800
pdt 2.2.1.v20101001-2300

doesn't happen outside of php tags.

Comment: it gets better when i disable
"preferences->java->editor->advanced->pde api tools proposals"
(i don't use java, and autocomplete still seems to work)

Comment: No joy for me there, Ben. I can turn off Content Assist entirely (for PHP), remove all Templates, disable all "Automatically close" options, drastically increasing memory limits in eclipse.ini, and it still feels like I'm typing on a 300 baud modem. As I type, I watch dtruss (I'm on a Mac) and see that Eclipse loads hundreds of source files (type four characters, watch the stat64s, type four more characters, watch the stat64 for the same files, rinse/repeat), and nothing I've tried seems to be able to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off white-space characters worked for me. Pretty annoying..

I couldn't recreate it on-demand and it never seemed to start at any particular point. I work on large projects with large include paths. Restarting Eclipse never had any effect. I had to restart my OS to resolve the issue. Finally find that disabling whitespace-chars all but resolved the speed issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same problem with very slow typing within PHP tags.  There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326261).

Even though that bug has a status of 'new' it appears there is a fix because I resolved the problem by updating my Eclipse PDT installation.  Go to the Help menu, and choose "Check for Updates", then install latest PDT updates.  I'm now on Helios Service Release 2, Build id: 20110301-1815 and I no longer see the problem (I hope that bug is gone for good.)