# Eclipse very slow

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm programming in PHP (PDO).
I have done this in gedit, but now I'm using Eclipse.
The problem is that it is very slow. First I worked with a FTP connection and edited the PHP files directly in the FTP connection.

I have done some research and found these links:

- [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495913/slow-typing-in-between-php-tags-with-eclipse-helios-with-pdt)
  — my problem is that the slowness is throughout the whole document.
- [Blog posting](http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/09/21/Tricks-to-speed-up-Eclipse-PHP-Helios-PDT-2.2)
  — I have tried all the tips, but without good results.

I have tried to edit files on my hard drive, but that does not work for me either.

I'm working on ubuntu 12.04, with a Intel dual core 2.4GHz 4GB RAM.
My computer is about 3 years old. 
I hope you can help me with this! It is very irritating.

Comment: I don't understand why it's offtopic? There are 26489 eclipse tags.

Comment: Erm, I must apologise. This is not off topic. I am the one who should be reading the FAQ. Too much coffee today, trigger happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try tuning the settings of the JVM in which you run eclipse, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) post here on StackOverflow that list best settings for eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But new my eclipse isn't working anymore. But I found I'm using a verry old version. I will download another version new.

Comment: Ok, however a tuning of the configuration could be necessary for achieving best performance even new versions ...

Comment: I know, but I had versoin 1.1, and the configuration files you gives, where for version 3.5.

Comment: It works! I have download the last version of eclipse. I will edit the config file, if it won't work again.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I've noticed a good performance improvement setting the Theme to Classic (was GTK).

Window -> Preferences, General, Appearance, change Theme to Classic, click Apply, restart Eclipse.

Of course eclipse.ini JVM settings also help, but I've already done that before, and besides already mentioned by the other answer.